# Getting Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function in recent days

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter values from an API result using JS grep function based on user input.

The API contains two string values & one integer value.

The grep function is working fine for string values but not working for integer value.

For example :

Name : 'Test'
Country : 'India'
Phone : 9999999999

If the user input is  Name or Country the grep function grep the values from API and returns the item, But if the user input is integer it throws the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Phone.indexOf is not a function
```

The interesting thing here is that the code has been working fine for the last 6 months but it throws this error very recently.

I am unable to find out why it works previously and why it stopped working recently.

Solutions or suggestions much appreciated !!!!

Comment: try to make the Phone as `String(Phone)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number type does not have a function called `indexOf`. Maybe in the previous times API was returning a *string representation of that number* and so `indexOf` was working for it.